# Gradle can't find Gson 2.5

Tags: gradle, gson, java-6

I'm under Java 6 and I need to use Google Gson v2.5 in order to support some behavior. Whenever I set the Gson version to 2.5 in the build.gradle file, it fails and says it cannot find that version. However, when I upgrade it to 2.6 it does find it and builds. The problem with 2.6 is that in some tests I get the `Unsupported major.minor version 51` error, so I need to work with 2.5

I'm using gradle version `2.14-rc-5`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with the necessary build files.

Comment: @AndrewFan I've already stated that using version 2.5 of Google Gson is not working, do you want me to post the complete `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using the gson which are compiled with higher java version in lower jdk project. For example, gson 2.6 is compiled with java version 1.7. you can verify this by downloading source for gson 2.6 [here](https://github.com/google/gson/releases/tag/gson-parent-2.6) and check for `<java.version>1.7</java.version>` in the `pom.xml` file and you are trying to use it in your project which is java 1.6 project. So to solve this issue you can stick to gson 2.5 version for now or upgrade your project to java 1.7.

Note- java 1.6 is obsolete for a while now.

Comment: yes, the problem is that when I set the Gson version in build.gradle tu be 2.5, and then i `gradle build` it cannot find the Gson 2.5 version.

Comment: I think you need to add mavenLocal() and mavenCentral() in your build.gradle repositories.